# Matplotlib plus NetworkX producing overlaying graphs when looping over multiple files

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, networkx

I have a script that should loop over series of csv files to create different directed graphs. When saving with matplotlib (plt.savefig()) then graphs seems to get saved on top of one another as the loop goes on. If I use plt.show() which requires me to manually close the file for each loop, this does not happen. The same if I do through the debugger. Can anyone give me any advice on what might be happening?

```
"""Script to read in CSV file with relations (after having processed with weighting),
and then make a tree hierarchy of relations
"""
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os


#create graph
def panda_tree():  
    path = './CONLL_test/weighted/weighted_out/'
    filelist = os.listdir(path)
    i = 1
    # read in files as dataframe and change to lists
    for file in filelist:
        if file.endswith('csv'):
            parent_child_rel = pd.read_csv(path+file)
            parents = parent_child_rel['parent']
            children = parent_child_rel['child']

            # change lists to tuples
            relations = pd.DataFrame({'from': parents, 'to': children})
            print(relations)

            # Build your graph
            graph_name = 'G%s' %i
            graph_name=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(relations, 'from', 'to', create_using=nx.DiGraph())

            # Plot it
            nx.draw(graph_name, with_labels=True)
            filename = os.path.splitext(file)
            (f, ext) = filename
            plt.savefig(path+'directed/'+f+'_dirgraph.png')
            i+=1

def main():
    panda_tree()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main ()
```

The files are dataframes containing increasingly less data as I include data only if it has over 10, 20, and so on hits up to 100. The 100 graph is the busiest one and when I run it on its own I don't have this problem. Has anyone else ever had this problem or can anyone give me a hint as to how to overcome it? The data is parent child relations (pairs).

Comment: Can you add some sample data that is enough to reproduce the problem you're having?

Comment: Try adding `plt.clf()` after `plt.savefig()`

Comment: Thank you! That worked, I had been trying to clear the wrong thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you were not clearing `fig` which is a global object created by `pyplot`. This means every time around your loop more data is added ("graphs seems to get saved on top of one another").

To avoid this, you can either call `plt.clf()` or `plt.close()` after your call to `plt.save_fig()`.

If you are creating a lot of figures, you should definitely prefer `plt.close()`, since `plt.clf()` does not release the memory used for each figure.